# Made the USB Drive as Swap Partition, Installed it, How to undo it{Ubuntu 10.10}

Tags: usb, swap, partitioning, ubuntu-10.10

Well,it was a very stupid thing to do on my part, But I made a 500 GB USB connected Hard Disk as my swap partition (thinking it will be only used during installation) and installed Ubuntu10.10.

I intend to create a different partition, on the same USB drive if needed(lets stick to this at the moment, if not I am open to creating a different swap space on the internal hard disk) and use the USB drive for my work on Ubuntu.

Can you suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove it from `/etc/fstab` and restart.
Alternatively you can disable it immediately (temporarly) with `swapoff`.

Comment: Ohh that will do? I opened the /etc/fstab but was reluctant to change it, as I was not sure, if the file system will change or not.

Comment: I edited the fstab and restarted it, still it doesnt show. How do I mount it?

Comment: Its not showing up on /media folder

Comment: It is not visible in media because it has no file system (ext3) etc.
I assume the disk is not used anymore. Thus arrange partitions and
prepare valid file systems using System > Administration > Disk Utility. Your USB drive should be there.